# PHP Pear Mail not sending email with special characters

Tags: php, email, special-characters, pear

I have the following problem. I have an online application form in HTML posting to a php file. The php file should send the contents via email. It works perfectly except when the client's name posting has special characters such as ü etc. It does not give any errors on form submission it just does not send the email.

This is my code:

```
  $host = "192.168.10.14";
$username = "exxxx@xxx.com";
$password = "xxxxx";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = new Mail_mime(array("text_charset" => "utf-8",
                            "html_charset" => "utf-8",
                            "eol" => "\n"));
    foreach ($headers as $name => $value){
    $headers[$name] = $mail->encodeHeader($name, $value, "utf-8",
                                                           "quoted-printable");
    }
// also encode to value
$to = $mail->encodeHeader("to", $to, "utf-8", "quoted-printable");
// fetch message
$msgDone = $mail->get();
// let Mail_Mime finish the headers (adds e.g. MIME info)
$headers_done = $mail->headers($headers);
// send the email

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail2)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {



header("Refresh: 0;url=OK.html");

  }
```

It works perfectly unless there are special characters. When there are special characters it does not send the email at all without any warnings.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post examples of the output (the contents of $to, $headers and $body) when it goes wrong?

Comment: How can I export this output please? How can I see it? thanks

Comment: This is basic PHP! `var_dump($to, $headers, $body);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your input before allowing it to be sent?

Would you allow an apostrophe to be entered in to an SQL statement without escaping it? Also check your mail logs on the server - that should provide a better hint to the underlying issue.

Thanks,
//P

Comment: What do you mean by "Have you tried cleaning your input before allowing it to be sent?" please? I have checked mail logs but the email does not even reach the server. thanks

Comment: In the same way that you would not allow the apostrophe in an SQL statement (you would escape this! to prevent a hacker jumping in and putting something that should not there and breaking the database and dumping data she should not see)- in the same way it is wise to escape  any "special" character put in to your mailer - HTH's and makes sense :-)